# Magento 2 API with Angular 2 Token authentication

Tags: api, angular, authentication, token, magento2

This is integration issue. Your help is much appreciated (Hint || Guide)

I have both Angular2 and Magento2 (bitnami) installed locally. Magento conf was changed to have the right headers (See below) for CROS.
I'm calling Magento2  from Angular2 to get the token and I'm getting the following issue:

OPTIONS http://192.168.56.1:82/magento/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token 400 (Bad Request)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.56.1:82/magento/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

## EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null

Angular 2 side:

```js
let headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
 headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE');
 headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin,Authorization,X-Auth-Token,Accept,Content-Type');
 headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); 
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post( 'http://192.168.56.1:82/magento/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token',
                      JSON.stringify('{"username":"angUser", "password":"angUser2017"}'),
                      options)
                      .map(res => res.json());
```

Magento2 API User
    angUser / angUser2017
    Consumer Key:           5bhvi7gjvyafcp35rajuxh0y4me2plga
    Consumer secret:        yh1nefyw1u80rd0ip1q6f8pijv9x72f1
    Access Token:           g5plfwth2rhlwtuwfhhqp7mg6sebrxc3
    Access Token Secret:        i1f4t7j65oo8ydtnteub9xr7wrswe99c

Magento headers:
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: True
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue before and I tracked it down to [this method](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.5/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/Rest/Request.php#L168) where there is no check for `->isOptions()`. So every API call from another domain was triggering a `Request method is invalid` exception.

```
/**
 * Retrieve current HTTP method.
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
 */
public function getHttpMethod()
{
    if (!$this->isGet() && !$this->isPost() && !$this->isPut() && !$this->isDelete()) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException(new Phrase('Request method is invalid.'));
    }
    return $this->getMethod();
}
```

You can find a possible workaround in the [github forum](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/API-CORS-requests-will-fail-without-OPTIONS-reponse/idi-p/60551) if you are using apache.

In my specific case what I ended up doing was serving both front-end and api from the same domain to avoid problems with CORS (I use nginx).

An example of the configuration needed for this can be something like:

```
location ~ ^/(index.php/)?rest {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location / { 
  root /var/www/angular/public/;
  index index.html;
}
```